# Xcode 11.3.1 Beta does not show corresponding custom class in assistant editor

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to create a project using Xcode 11.3.1 beta. I have added the `UICollectionView` and made an `Custom Class` for that and associated it with the cell in the storyboard.

But when I try to open that class in assistant editor it does not show up.

Like previously also it was not sometimes picking up the right corresponding class but then we could select the file `manually` but that option is missing here as it seems.

I cleared Derived data, restarted code but nothing is working. It's still showing the wrong class for the the UICollectionViewCell.

How do I resolve this?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Now that we have editor panes, there is really no need to use an Assistant pane. So just don’t use one. Use two normal editor panes and populate them however you like.